Cannot delete files from uploads folder after uploading to S3 from multer diskstorage
When creating or updating an item, I have to upload multiple images so I use multer diskstorage to store the items in an uploads folder and then upload to S3. I want to delete those files from diskstorage after uploading to s3, as I do not want to clog disk resources, However, when I try to delete files using fs unlink, it gives the following error:
Error deleting file uploads\22812ab9-e8a0-49de-9d4f-f637e5d9d1c2.jpg: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\_projects\bitkart\server\uploads\22812ab9-e8a0-49de-9d4f-f637e5d9d1c2.jpg']

I cannot upload directly to s3 beacuse I would have to refactor a lot of code, is there any way it could be done using multer and resolving the error?
I tried using try catch in create item controller:
export const createItem = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.user?.id;
    const {
      title,
      description,
      price,
      room_no,
      hostel_no,
      year_of_purchase,
      category,
      contact_no,
    } = req.body;

    const existingItem = await Item.findOne({ title, seller: userId });
    if (existingItem) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "You already have an item with this title" });
    }

    // Calculate total size
    const totalSize = (req.files as Express.Multer.File[]).reduce(
      (acc: number, file: Express.Multer.File) => acc + file.size,
      0
    );
    if (totalSize > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "Total file size exceeds the 25 MB limit." });
    }

    // Resize and upload each image
    const imageDetails = [];
    for (const file of req.files as Express.Multer.File[]) {
      const filePath = path.join("uploads", file.filename);
      try {
        // Resize the image and convert it to webp format
        const buffer = await sharp(filePath).toFormat("webp").toBuffer();
        const imageName = randomImageName();
        const params = {
          Bucket: bucketName!,
          Key: imageName,
          Body: buffer,
          ContentType: file.mimetype,
        };
        const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
        await s3.send(command);
        imageDetails.push({ key: imageName });
      } catch (uploadError) {
        console.error(`Error uploading file ${file.filename}:`, uploadError);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Error uploading file." });
      } finally {
        // Ensure the file is deleted from the disk after processing
        try {
          await fs.promises.unlink(filePath);
          console.log(`Successfully deleted ${filePath}`);
        } catch (unlinkError) {
          console.error(`Error deleting file ${filePath}:`, unlinkError);
        }
      }
    }

    const newItem = new Item({
      title,
      description,
      price,
      room_no,
      hostel_no,
      year_of_purchase,
      category,
      seller: userId,
      images: imageDetails,
      contact_no,
    });
    await newItem.save();

    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $push: { items: newItem._id } });

    res.status(201).json({ message: "Item created Successfully", newItem });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error", error });
  }
};

I also tried simply trying fs promises unlink in updateitems:
export const updateImages = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.user?.id;
    const itemId = req.params.id;
    const item = await Item.findById(itemId);

    if (!item || item.seller.toString() !== userId) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ message: "Item not found or not authorized" });
    }

    if (item.images.length >= 4) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "You cannot upload more than 4 images" });
    }

    if (!req.files || req.files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Please upload images" });
    }

    // Calculate total size of new images
    const totalSize = (req.files as Express.Multer.File[]).reduce(
      (acc: number, file: Express.Multer.File) => acc + file.size,
      0
    );
    if (totalSize > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "Total file size exceeds the 25 MB limit." });
    }

    // Resize and upload new images
    const newImages = [];
    for (const file of req.files as Express.Multer.File[]) {
      const filePath = path.join("uploads", file.filename);

      // Check if the file exists
      if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: `File not found: ${filePath}` });
      }

      // Resize the image
      const buffer = await sharp(filePath).toFormat("webp").toBuffer();
      const imageName = randomImageName();
      const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: imageName,
        Body: buffer,
        ContentType: file.mimetype,
      };
      const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
      await s3.send(command);
      newImages.push({
        url: `${process.env.CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN}${imageName}`,
        key: imageName,
      });

      // Delete the file from disk after uploading to S3
      fs.promises.unlink(filePath);
    }

    // Update images in item
    const updatedImages = [...item.images, ...newImages];
    item.images = updatedImages.slice(0, 4); // Ensure only 4 images are kept
    await item.save();

    res.json({ message: "Images updated successfully", item });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error", error });
  }
};

I also tried using just unlink, unlink async, promisify, but all give the same error

This error typically occurs when the file is being used by another process, or the process attempting to delete the file lacks sufficient permissions.

i wrapped (S3 upload, file deletion)  in a try-catch block to catch and handle any errors effectively.
await fs.promises.unlink(filePath); is now used to ensure the file deletion is awaited and properly handled.
Try with these changes
  try {
    // Resize the image
    const buffer = await sharp(filePath).toFormat("webp").toBuffer();
    const imageName = randomImageName();
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: imageName,
      Body: buffer,
      ContentType: file.mimetype,
    };
    const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
    await s3.send(command);
    newImages.push({
      url: `${process.env.CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN}${imageName}`,
      key: imageName,
    });

    // Delete the file from disk after uploading to S3
    await fs.promises.unlink(filePath);
    console.log(`Successfully deleted ${filePath}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error processing file ${filePath}:`, err);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error", error: err });
  }
}


Didn't work. It still gives the same error
